# How do I Make Reusable Class for Inventory/Item System? C#

Tags: c#, class, console

I want to make a class that I can use to make endless items and put them in a list, for my inventory system. I don't know a lot of C# so if there is an entirely different solution, I would be open to hearing it.

Here is what I tried.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Game
{
    public class Item
    {
        bool isChestArmor, isLegArmor, isOneHanded, isItem, isWeapon, hpItem, manaItem, onlyOffHand;
        double damage, resistance, cost;
        string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get {return name;}
            set {name = value;}
        }
        public double Damage
        {
            get {return damage;}
            set {damage = value;}
        }
        public double Resistance
        {
            get {return resistance;}
            set {resistance = value;}
        }
        public double Cost
        {
            get {return cost;}
            set {cost = value;}
        }
        public bool IsChestArmor 
        {
            get {return isChestArmor;}
            set {isChestArmor = value;}
        }
        public bool IsLegArmor 
        {
            get {return isLegArmor;}
            set {isLegArmor = value;}
        }
        public bool IsItem 
        {
            get {return isItem;}
            set {isItem = value;}
        }
        public bool IsWeapon 
        {
            get {return isWeapon;}
            set {isWeapon = value;}
        }
        public bool IsOneHanded
        {
            get {return isOneHanded;}
            set {isOneHanded = value;}
        }
        public bool OnlyOffHand 
        {
            get {return onlyOffHand;}
            set {onlyOffHand = value;}
        }
        public bool HpItem
        {
            get {return hpItem;}
            set {hpItem = value;}
        }
        public bool ManaItem
        {
            get {return manaItem;}
            set {manaItem = value;}
        }
    }
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Item I = new Item();
            List<Item> Inventory = new List<Item>();
            I.ManaItem = false;
            I.HpItem = false;
            I.OnlyOffHand = false;
            I.IsChestArmor = false;
            I.IsLegArmor = false;
            I.IsWeapon = true;
            I.Damage = 10;
            I.Cost = 75;
            I.Resistance = 0;
            I.Name = "Short Sword";
            Inventory.Add(I);
            Console.WriteLine(Inventory[0].Name);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
```

This doesn't work because I would need a new class for every iteration of an item. It would be nice if there was a way to make duplicates of the Item class, and I'm sure there is a way to do this, I just simply don't know how.
Thank you.

Comment: If you need many instances of _Item_ you create, with _new_, a new Item instance and then assign the instance to the same variable. So, each time you call new and set the variable _I_ with the _new_ "result" you have _I_ "pointing" to the new instance while the previous one is kept inside the list.

Comment: Properties staring with `Is...` are a hint that you need to read up on polymorphism (inheritance hierarchies). For example, you might want to define an interface `IItem` then interfaces derived from that for ore specific types of items e.g. `IWeapon`. Finally, have concrete classes implement the appropriate interface e.g. `public class Longsword : IWeapon`

Comment: Would that allow me to make duplicates of the Item interface and add that to a list? @EricJ.

Comment: You would want your list to be `List<IItem>`. You can add anything that implements `IItem` or any subclass like `IWeapon` to that same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think this is the core learning you're looking for in the question.

This problem calls for an understanding of polymorphism, or the representation of related concepts in an inheritance hierarchy. Here's one way you can approach that in C#.

(Update to original answer: Added `DancingSword` that can act like a weapon and like armor).

```
namespace Game
{
    public enum ArmorLocation
    {
        All, Head, Chest, Leg, Foot
    }
    public interface IItem
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IWeapon : IItem
    {
        double Damage { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IArmor : IItem
    {
        double Resistance { get; set; }
        ArmorLocation Location { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weapon : IWeapon
    {
        public double Damage { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DancingSword : IWeapon, IArmor
    {
        public double Damage { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Resistance { get; set; }
        public ArmorLocation Location { get; set; }
    }

    public class Armor : IArmor
    {
        public double Resistance { get; set; }
        public ArmorLocation Location { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var Inventory = new List<IItem>();
            Inventory.Add(new Weapon() { Name = "Shortsword", Damage = 10.0 });
            Inventory.Add(new Armor() { Name = "Steel Helm", Location = ArmorLocation.Head, Resistance = 3.0 });
            Inventory.Add(new Armor() { Name = "Skeeverhide Boots", Location = ArmorLocation.Foot, Resistance = 1.0 });
            Inventory.Add(new DancingSword() { Name = "Dancing Sword +1", Damage = 8.0, Location = ArmorLocation.All, Resistance = 1.0 });

            Console.WriteLine("Weapon items:");
            foreach (var item in Inventory.OfType<IWeapon>())
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);

            Console.WriteLine("Armor items:");
            foreach (var item in Inventory.OfType<IArmor>())
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, that is a lot of information, so tell me if I got this straight. IWeapon and IArmor ar inheriting from IItem, Weapon is inheriting from IWeapon and IItem, Armor from IArmor and IItem, Armor also gets a custom variable ArmorLocation that has 4 options. Then MainClass adds duplicates of Weapon and Armor to a list. Right?

Comment: "IWeapon and IArmor ar inheriting from IItem." Correct. "Weapon is inheriting from IWeapon and IItem". Close. Weapon _implements_ those two interfaces, which is conceptually similar.

Comment: @AdmiralCaleb101 I updated the answer to show how one class can behave like two different things. In some languages this is achieved by multiple inheritance. In C#, it's achieved by implementing multiple interfaces.

Comment: I am running into a bug where the Inventory list is being cleared after every frame.  I can use it once then the item just disappears. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think that would be a new question. You'll need to show the code for that issue.

Comment: It's a thousand lines of code. I'll just figure it out myself.

Comment: The problem is that the list is being remade blank every frame but I can't put it in a Start() because then I can't access it from my main method. If I put it in a if(onStart) then I still can't access it, or the class that the main method is in.

Comment: I fixed it by using a list variable instead of var. Thank you for your help Eric.

Comment: @AdmiralCaleb101: Glad you got it working! FYI, `var` is syntactic sugar for "whatever type the compiler can infer from the right hand side of the assignment." That means `var Inventory = new List<IItem>();` and `List<IItem> Inventory = new List<IItem>();` produce the same result.